# Fibonacci recursive function with an output of the array of the sequence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, fibonacci

Hi I was trying to come up with a function to return a fibonacci sequence, that is an array not the usual last n-th fibonacci number.

```
function fib(n,arr=[0]) {
  if (n===0||n===1) {
    arr.push(n)
    return arr;
  }
  let arr2 = fib(n-2);
  let arr1 = fib(n-1);
  arr1.push(arr2[arr2.length-1]+arr1[arr1.length-1]);
  return arr1;
}
```

it works fine but I am not happy with the hard coded arr=[0] here. I tried to put arr=[] instead but the sequence I ended up getting excluded the first 0 entries in the array which should've been there.

I am sure there's better approaches to solve this.

P.S: I want to solve this using a recursive approach and I know it has a poor exponential time complexity but I just wanted to pratice my recursive programming skills.

Comment: What's the usage of that array as param?

Comment: Just as a note: one can certainly overdo avoiding hard coding values. The problem with hard coded values is that they make code less readable and less flexible, but 1's and 0's **often** don't suffer from these negative side affects.

Answer (score 5):

```
  let arr2 = fib(n-2);
  let arr1 = fib(n-1);
```

You build up two arrays for each step, so you build up n! arrays... Instead just use one recursive call, e.g.:

```
 function fibonacci(n){
   if(n <= 2)
      return [0, 1].slice(0, n);
   const res = fibonacci(n - 1);
   res.push(res[res.length - 1] + res[res.length - 2])
   return res;
 }
```

---

But do you really need recursion?:

```
 function fibonacci(n){
   const arr = [0, 1].slice(0 , n);
   for(let i = 2; i < n; i++)
     arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
   return arr;
 }
```

Comment: `fibonacci(1)` is not `[0,1,1]`, your code returns wrong values

Comment: yea I know that iterative approach. I used recurssion just for practice. thanks.

Comment: Why do you use slice at this line? `return [0, 1].slice(0, n);` at the Recursive version? Without slice it exactly gives the same result? `return [0, 1]`

Comment: @scaryguy nope, for `fibonacci(1)` it would return the wrong result

Answer (score 0):

Not my proudest code, but has array+recursion. Works fine with n>=2 (will not return `[1]`):

```js
function fibo(n){
  var ret=[1,1];
  function recurs(n){
    if(!ret[n-1])recurs(n-1);
    //if(!ret[n-2])recurs(n-2); // it is not necessary in fact
    ret[n]=ret[n-1]+ret[n-2];
  }
  if(n>2)recurs(n-1);
  return ret;
}
console.log(fibo(2).join());
console.log(fibo(15).join());
```

Comment: @ZhenghaoHe in terms of Fibonacci-generation it would be iterative. In fact, this one also builds the list iteratively, that ```ret[n]=...``` line could be a simple ```ret.push(...)``` and would provide the exact same result. So the "recursion" directly replaces a simple ```for``` loop, which is not something I would be proud of. The only "plus" part is that it builds a single list only.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive fibonacci is easy, but how about making it *tail-recursive*?

```
let fib = n => fib2(2, n, [0, 1]);
let fib2 = (k, n, a) => k >= n ? a :
    fib2(k + 1, n, a.concat(a[k - 1] + a[k - 2]));
```

If you're a happy user of the Safari browser, whose JS engine already implements the ES6 tail call spec, you can test it with this snippet (warning: might take significant time or exhaust the memory!)

```js
'use strict';

const BIG = 1e5;


let fibNaive = n => {
    if (n <= 2)
        return [0, 1].slice(0, n);
    const res = fibNaive(n - 1);
    res.push(res[res.length - 1] + res[res.length - 2])
    return res;
};

try {
    console.log('naive', fibNaive(BIG).slice(0, 100));
} catch(e) {
    console.log('naive', e.message) // RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
}


let fibCool = n => fib2(2, n, [0, 1]);
let fib2 = (k, n, a) => k >= n ? a :
    fib2(k + 1, n, a.concat(a[k - 1] + a[k - 2]));

console.log('cool', fibCool(BIG).slice(0, 100)) // works!
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var fib = function(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return [0, 1];
  } else {
    var arr = fib(n - 1);
    arr.push(arr[arr.length - 1] + arr[arr.length - 2]);
    return arr;
  }
};

console.log(fib(8));
```

Comment: did you really look at my question? of course I know there is this good old solution. but I wanted to output the array of the sequence not the value of the n-th fibonacci value